# undefined reference to `Fork'

Tags: c, process

I'm testing the waters with process control code and came across this reference issue with compiling my fork.c.
specs: linux running on x86-64.
fork.c:

```
#include "csapp.h"
int main() 
{
int i;
for(i = 3; i > 0; i--)
{
Fork();
}
printf("Example\n");
exit(0);
}
```

A ls of the contents of the current directory is csapp.h  fork.c and the link to csapp.h is found in this link: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ics2/code/include/csapp.h.
Any help is appreciated. I continue to get this error when running gcc fork.c
`/tmp/cc7SNljK.o: In function`main':
fork.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `Fork'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: What you've included is a header, it doesn't contain the function it's just the signature of the function. The function should be defined in a library somewhere and you need to link that library  to you can use the function. Check if you find some kind of `csapp.so` or `csapp.a` file somewhere in `code/lib/` or where the library folder is. Then you'll need to use gcc's `-L` and `-l` flags to link the library.

Comment: [POSIX defines `fork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) ... not `Fork()`

Comment: using fork() instead of Fork() it worked. I understand I only have the signature in the header file that i included in the main program file.

Comment: Re "*Using fork() instead of Fork() it worked.*", In a sense, sure. But I imagine you're suppose to use `Fork` for your assignment, whatever it does.